# import "C" is unsupported in test - looking for alternatives

Tags: go

I am using some shared c code in golang that I want to test. import "C" is not supported in "go test". Have you seen any alternatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put the `cgo` code in a non-test file in your package. You can then wrap any "C" calls with private go functions for testing.